# Parsing XML in C

Tags: xml

How to parse XML response coming from the server in C. Do we have any standard libraries for it? Can some one provide me any idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [libxml](http://xmlsoft.org/)
- [expat](http://www.libexpat.org/)

[Benchmarks](http://xmlbench.sourceforge.net/results/benchmark200901/index.html) also exist to help you compare the two. libxml seems to be faster and have more functionality.

Answer (score 3):

See [Gnome](http://xmlsoft.org/) (libxml) and [expat](http://expat.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

In additional to SAX based parsing, there is also [vtd-xml](http://vtd-xml.sf.net)

Answer (score 0):

Another SAX parser would be Xerces : http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/